# Calling a member struct inside a member function

Tags: c++, qt, class, oop, struct

Let's say I have a class, named `Test`. Inside that, I have declared a struct named `testResults`. Then I have written a member function, named `performTest()`. I want this function to change the values of struct variables (it also takes other inputs). Here is what I have done:

*(Note: I have reduced the codes to make it less troublesome for you to inspect)*

in header:

```
class Test : public BaseHardwareTest
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Test(QObject *parent = 0);
    struct testResults {
        int testOneRes[15];
        int testTwoRes[5];
    };

    int performTest(int arg1, int arg2, struct testResults &testRes);

signals:

public slots:

};
```

in source:

```
int Test::performTest(int arg1, int arg2, Test::testResults &testRes)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        if(arg1 < 12)
            testRes.testOneRes[i] = -1;
        else
            testRes.testOneRes[i] = 1;  
    } 

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        if(arg2 < 33)
            testRes.testTwoRes[i] = -1;
        else
            testRes.testTwoRes[i] = 1; 
    }

    return 1;
}
```

This was one of my various tries. This one does not out any errors but I can't use it. ***I can't access the member struct from my main***. I am a newbie of OOP concept and I can't make it work.

Is there anything wrong on header/source sections? If not, how can I call this function? Any help?

> **[EDIT] PROBLEM SOLVED:**
>
> It turned out that the problem is about totally another thing. I use
>   two projects (one is a library and the other one is for testing the
>   library. Let's call them **testLib** and **tester**, respectively)
>   which have dependency. When I change things in **testlib** project, I
>   have to go to related **testLib** location from **main.cpp** of **tester** in order
>   to make my IDE see the changes and makes related updates. Since I was
>   working in two seperate text editor windows and didn't do what I've
>   said above, my IDE didn't see the new members of the `Test` class and
>   didn't suggest me when I type `Test:: testRes`--. And this made me
>   think that I couldn't access the new member struct. Thanks everybody
>   for help.

Comment: Please show `main`'s code. It should be as easy as `Test::testResults`.

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't access the member struct from my main"; what is the error ? Show more code.

Comment: Show us `main()`, also you don't need `struct testResults &testRes`, you need only `testResults &testRes`

Answer (score 1):

`struct testResults` is not a *member* of the class, it's just a type declaration.  You don't access it as if were actual data within the class.  I *think* that's what you're saying, so that may be the confusion.

Instead, you create an instance as follows:

```
Test::testResults myresults;
```

Now you can pass `myresults` to an instance of your Test class' `performTest`method.

```
Test mytest;
Test::testResults myresults;

// Assumes "QString" (whatever it is) has a constructor that takes a string:
mytest.performTest("Hello", "Goodbye", myresults);
```

Comment: Thank you, Bob. It turned out to be a classic newbie mistake. (I am pretty sure that yesterday, my IDE did not show me `testResults` under the class `Test` though. And I have no idea why)

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're defining the wrong function. You define `int Test::performTest(int arg1, int arg2, DDRTest::testResults &testRes)`, however, you *should* define `int Test::performTest(QString arg1, QString arg2, Test::testResults &testRes)`.

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to reduce my original code and it seems that I couldn't do it properly. Thanks for the warning.

Answer (score 1):

You have a mismatch between your h-file and cpp-file:

in h-file you have:

```
int performTest(QString arg1, QString arg2, struct testResults &testRes);
```

should be

```
int performTest(int arg1, int arg2, testResults &testRes)
```

and in your cpp-file:

```
int Test::performTest(int arg1, int arg2, DDRTest::testResults &testRes)
```

should be

```
int Test::performTest(int arg1, int arg2, Test::testResults &testRes)
```

You see the difference?

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to reduce my original code and apparently I forgot to change the header part. Now I've just edited the part you mentioned in my question, thanks.